# How to disallow extensions outside Firefox profile directory

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

Some softwares like Kaspersky Internet Security, AVG, JRE and many others install their firefox add-on outside my profile directory and I cannot uninstall it, only disable it. And when I try to create another profile, they still here and I have to disable it again

So, is there any way to disallow extensions outside Firefox profile directory? Registry hacks or Environment variables? Many thanks

EDIT: I want to ask about disallow Window registry extensions http://kb.mozillazine.org/Uninstalling_add-ons#Windows_Registry_extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try installing FF and then denying access on the installation "extensions" directory for creating a new file to the group "Everyone".

For the registry installed extensions, you should be able to deny access to the registry path/key.  This is easily done with regedit - locate the registry entity you want to change and use the context menu to change permissions on it.  **Be very careful; changing the registry in the wrong way can prevent your system from booting.** Make careful note of what you do and have a recovery disk with regedit handy just in case.

Comment: Yes, it's useful for global extensions, but don't work for registry extensions (extensions that use registry key to install)

Comment: Can you explain more about "deny access to the registry path/key"? Any software or mechanism?

Comment: Right click the registry key and select "Permissions". On a 32bit OS that would be HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Firefox\Extensions while on a 64bit OS it would be HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Mozilla\Firefox\Extensions